# How do I reverse engineer this "power of"/exponent?

Tags: exponentiation

Take the following:

```
(2)^3 = 8
```

I understand that this is

```
2 * 2 * 2 = 8
```

My question is how do I reverse engineer this if I do not know the power like this:

```
(2)^x = 8
```

What is the value of x?

x could potentially contain a decimal and so could the result:

```
(2)^1.5 = 2.82842712474619
```

So without any numbers it would be:

```
(y)^x = z
```

How do I find out what x is?

```
x = ?
```

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is "take logs". The [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), or log, of a number reflects what power you need to raise a certain base to in order to get that number.

For interesting but complicated reasons, the number $e=2.718281828...$ is often used as the base, in which case the "log" function is written "$\ln$" ("natural logarithm"), but any other base $b$ will work the same way ("$\log_b$") for the equation you're interested in.

The reason this works is that $\ln y^x = x\ln y$, so

$$x=\frac{\ln z}{\ln y}$$

---

(The reason this is consistent with [@amWhy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125301/how-do-i-reverse-engineer-this-power-of-exponent/1125308#1125308) is because $\frac{\log_a b}{\log_a c}=\log_c b$.)

Answer (score 12):

See [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm). That's essentially the inverse function of an exponential function. In your case $$2^x = 8 \iff x = \log_2(8)$$

In general: 
$$a^x = b \iff x = \log_a(b)$$